# Global file pointer?

Tags: python, file, global, readline

Currently my code is set up with multiple functions reading from a single file. I tried to simplify things by using a global file pointer, but with no success:

```
file = open('filename')

def A():
    global file
    line = file.readline()
    ...
    B()
    ...
    line = file.readline()

def B():
    global file
    line = file.readline()
    ...
```

In the example above, my goal is to read a few lines with A, read a few lines with B, and then have A pick up from where B left off. However, the readline() call in A stays in its original place. For what I'm trying to do, would this be possible using global variables?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Can you show an actual example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: So what you're saying is that if *filename* is a three-line file, `A` reads the first line, `B` reads the second line, and then `A` reads the second line again rather than reading the third line? I find that hard to believe. (Besides, it doesn't look like there's anything preventing you from simply passing the `file` variable as a parameter to each of those functions. *That* would "simplify things.")

Comment: I can confirm that's not what would happen, can you show your actual code and input? Something else must be happening.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `global file` is not necessary since you aren't trying to reassign to the name `file`.

Comment: Oh wow! Novice mistake on my part.I was using a while loop to check the new line in A(), but forgot to update the line I was checking. Once I added the fix, the code works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to tell and set your position in a file, use file.seek() and file.tell()

For more help, please put in a complete example, so we can see your actual issue. For me it carries through the file position in python 3.4.3 on windows 7.